# How to align 0 value in multiple y axis layered chart in Vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

In Vega-lite, I want to align y-axis values, so that zeroes are in the same place and negative values go below x-axis. Is it possible to do in Vega-lite? I can't hardcode the domain limits, as the data passed to this chart is dynamic, thus can be different every time.

My code:

```
{
   "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
   "width":300,
   "data":{
      "values":[
         {
            "key":"Type A",
            "sum1":"1000",
            "sum2":"2000",
            "ratio":"15"
         },
         {
            "key":"Type B",
            "sum1":"1500",
            "sum2":"1500",
            "ratio":"-5"
         },
         {
            "key":"Type C",
            "sum1":"2000",
            "sum2":"1000",
            "ratio":"7"
         }
      ]
   },
   "layer":[
      {
         "mark":{
            "type":"bar",
            "size":15,
            "xOffset":0
         },
         "encoding":{
            "y":{
               "field":"sum1",
               "type":"quantitative",
               "axis":{
                  "title":null,
                  "ticks":true,
                  "orient":"left"
               }
            },
            "x":{
               "field":"key",
               "type":"nominal",
               "axis":{
                  "title":null,
                  "labelAngle":-45,
                  "labelLimit":1000
               }
            },
            "color":{
               "datum":"Sum1"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "mark":{
            "type":"bar",
            "size":15,
            "xOffset":15
         },
         "encoding":{
            "y":{
               "field":"sum2",
               "type":"quantitative",
               "axis":{
                  "domain":false,
                  "title":null,
                  "labels":false,
                  "ticks":false
               }
            },
            "x":{
               "field":"key",
               "type":"nominal",
               "axis":{
                  "title":null,
                  "labelAngle":-45,
                  "labelLimit":1000
               }
            },
            "color":{
               "datum":"Sum2"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "mark":{
            "type":"line",
            "interpolate":"monotone",
            "clip":true
         },
         "encoding":{
            "y":{
               "type":"quantitative",
               "field":"ratio",
               "axis":{
                  "title":null,
                  "ticks":true,
                  "orient":"right"
               }
            },
            "x":{
               "field":"key",
               "type":"nominal",
               "axis":{
                  "title":null,
                  "labelAngle":-45,
                  "labelLimit":1000
               }
            },
            "color":{
               "datum":"Ratio"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "resolve":{
      "scale":{
         "y":"independent"
      }
   },
   "config":{
      "legend":{
         "orient":"bottom",
         "columns":3,
         "labelLimit":500,
         "layout":{
            "bottom":{
               "anchor":"middle"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVABrOAE80IACrOccAAQBBRRAIBgQARjdQvR1A4IQAJjc4qMCAJyN2CLEQAF8FRxc3T28fACEYkPD0ULE9cvjM2qU0zAz0fizc-Nd0It8AYTrKkCTGoJCEquSm9LY3AHYcgF1ckEEkZzgUu1BkFIc0UEwvODcmJC2lCBoALxPUaqUADwB5ADNXiDhMNB0VuFkoGw1DRZGQDiBuqBXjQ4II1G5YuElEdvG4AI4MJCyFrGFqkQJIR40GymEA4wR3WQMQSCZE0KAOEmYFJWJRsFIw7FuCmvb7ZFaPcHQ2Hw9BOVzI45uWRsBAgiwEokkw50CloKk0pRrJiwvygtWofgAFjEWqQOsEABkaHLvvcovylIDBOzwYZMCE3ABlCo5R07c77Ukou4gM4XII3O4PEAvd6fO3VP4AoEgsGkyEgYVwhHjQIh9GY7F0dL4pSE4lu2VIEFoV4WT50zAGjW01bm2Ek+uCRtk+mMusNuCO2NCmE5sUFSWo9AyuWyBXlpXg8mU6lt7W6-V3Y2m9sW622tCRPQj52u0nuz3oH31fmdEC7IOHKXoYSyE5KEGYTY4NhrH83AQOQ2EwORPxAKBhBwNBmSsZNAWBUFwUzAt0AxLEcVLCDs1FEBmgyJdK2DVU101PsGSZFk4DZDl-jtfCaDILA-SeMcRTccV81fEA53lQRFWIlVmzIjcO0EPUyANXczQPG06GPB0VnPLZLyMa8QAAJRmP1skWJprH-fFSWgCw7lAboQBBNQ4G8WQbK5M85GhdNQApMh-lFUB2U5BimFAsCEECZ0QlkEktFk2FDwU1Aan0dtnDYBg7VAfzsFlcEsVgC9H3UNQ1XvfkgA)

[image: Chart]